# Contextual filter for an indirect taxonomy term?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I know how to display similarly tagged items of a different content type in a view block ([here is a good explanation and settings picture](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/50030/39617)).

I have a scenario where the term IDs aren't *directly* associated with both content types. The term reference field on the page content type is attached, not to the view content type itself, but to **another taxonomy that is attached to the view content type** (the view content type uses a taxonomy that has a field which is also used in the page content type).

How can I filter my view to items that are "mapped to" the term?

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase (to see if I understood correctly):
You have a content type pointing to term reference #1, that is pointing to term reference #2. You want to show the content that points to term #1, with the context being term #2.

In that case, you'd need to create a relationship (see [Using Views Contextual Filter and Relationship to display reference on referenced node](https://www.drupal.org/node/1841004))

(The following explanation would work best with [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) instead of term reference - I don't use that field type so I'm not sure the relationship exists with it)

But in short, you'd create a relationship to "referencing entity from field_term_reference" (the field on term #1 pointing to term #2). From there you could create the "referencing entity" relationship from the field on the content type pointing to term #1. The contextual filter would be to the term ID #2 using that relationship.